# tmux no server running on /private/tmp/tmux-502/default

Tags: macos, tmux, macos-sierra

On macOS 10.12.1

tmux 2.3

When run:

```
tmux source-file ~/.tmux.conf
```

Got error:

```
no server running on /private/tmp/tmux-502/default
```

Answer (score 12):

I was getting the same error when running a script that automatically configures tmux workspaces and then attaches them.

However, when I ran the `tmux` command by itself, I got a more useful error. It told me that a few lines of my `~/.tmux.conf` file were causing errors. They're out of date, I guess.

I commented out these lines and now everything works. Maybe that'll work for you, too?

Comment: My problem were lines related to be able to copy-paste like vim.  bind-key -t vi-copy v begin-selection (and 3 more commands)

Answer (score 3):

You must not run

```
tmux source-file ~/.tmux.conf
```

1. `~/.tmux.conf` is launched automatically once on the tmux server start.
2. If you need use other alternative.conf file, you must use '-f' option:
   `tmux -f alternative.conf`
3. If you need run a source file, looked like the server must be started first, if it is not yet started:
   `tmux start-server \; source-file source.tmux`

Answer (score -2):

I will use [Iterm2](https://www.iterm2.com/) and brew

if you installed previously tmux please uninstall it, if you use brew with brew

```
brew uninstall tmux --force
```

then install it again

```
brew install tmux
```

and finally create a `.tmux.conf` file in your home directory

```
cd && cat > .tmux.conf                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
set-option -g mouse on

# make scrolling with wheels work
bind -n WheelUpPane if-shell -F -t = "#{mouse_any_flag}" "send-keys -M" "if -Ft= '#{pane_in_mode}' 'send-keys -M' 'select-pane -t=; copy-mode -e; send-keys -M'"
bind -n WheelDownPane select-pane -t= \; send-keys -M
```

type Ctrl - d and thats all